# How can I restore /etc/profile?

Tags: .profile, etc

I'm working on a bash script that appends to `/etc/profile`, but instead of appending, I accidentally wrote over it, losing all of its content.

How can I restore the file? Is there a system default profile that I can copy to restore my `/etc/profile`?

I did search here but being new to Ubuntu, I don't know if the posted `/etc/profile` content I see in other questions is the default content.

Comment: `grep /etc/profile /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.postinst` shows  `/var/lib/dpkg/info/base-files.postinst`, which in turn has a function copying `profile` from `/usr/share/base-files` to `/etc/passwd` (among other such files).

Comment: Testing a script on your own OS, as root is not a good idea. You should use a VM (so you can just take a snapshot, and if anything goes wrong you just restore the snapshot), or at the very least backup your files before running it.

Comment: Why was this reopened? The duplicate covers cases where a copy of the original config file exists elsewhere on disk.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a copy of the system default `profile` in `/usr/share/base-files`